# How to use SEPA in braintree without asking for paypal account?

Tags: paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I integrated Braintree local payment methods in my project. One of the method is SEPA.
While clicking on the SEPA payment button, Braintree gateway is redirecting me to the SEPA payment page. Where a user has to enter bank details. Here on this page, the page is also forcing the user to enter PayPal account details or create a PayPal account.

My requirement is to use SEPA without entering PayPal details or creating an account.

How to achieve this using Braintree. If not what is the solution for my requirement?

Comment: This is an issue from the braintree's end. Don't worry, wait for it to be fixed :+1